# PHP - Store an array of strings found between tags with varying "id"?

Tags: php, xml, regex, preg-match

I have a Collada (.dae) file. Within the file there are a lot of tags of this format;

```
<float_array id="adsfsafdas" count="72">12 4 2 1 92 1</float_array>
```

I want to extract the string from between all these tags and populate an array, so in this example it'll save the string "12 4 2 1 92 1" into the array.

I have a function to find strings between two given strings but the "id" and "count" in the opening tag change for each one. From a bit of searching it seems that regular expressions are the way to go to match the pattern and "preg_match" might be of use.

Any tips about how to go about it? Thanks

**EDIT: Thanks for the advice - I got it working with the following code!**

```
<?PHP

//open collada file
$file = file_get_contents('samplecollada.dae');

//find all matches and populate array
preg_match_all("/\<float_array id\=\".+\" count\=\".+\"\>(.+)\<\/float_array\>/",$file, $results);

//output array to preview result
print_r($results[1]);

?>
```

Comment: Regexes for XML documents is a bad idea. Try to [parse XML instead](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)'s a basic reference of regex special characters. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)'s the documentation on PHP's `preg_match()`. What you want to do is match a literal `<float_array`, then a variable set of attributes (using something like `.*?` or `[^>]*?`, then a literal `>`, then the numbers (which you'll need to [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) so that you can backreference them), then the literal `</float_array>`. In PHP, you can pass a `$matches` variable to capture backreferences (again, see documentation above). If you use `/` as your delimiter, you'll need to escape your slashes within your regex with `\`. I'm sure you can piece the rest together.

Comment: Actually after further testing my solution isn't working and I have no idea why. preg_match_all isn't finding every instance, it is skipping over some. Yet if I copy that section of the file and instead of using `$file = file_get_contents(` I just paste in `$file = 'pasted section...';`, it DOES pick up the lines it missed when searching the whole file. I tried my regex on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it works for those skipped lines. Any ideas? Would it help if I read the file line by line instead?

Comment: @user1107685 Do you have lines with more than one set of `<float_array>`s? Because if you do, it might be the greedy searching that's gobbling up the extra sets in the same line. If this is the case, add a `U` modifier after the second delimiter.

Comment: @user1107685 Another possibility is that you have a `<float_array>` set that spans more than one line. In that case the `.+` won't match (because `.` doesn't match newlines). To change that, add a `s` modifier after the second delimiter.

Comment: No more than one tag per line. And tags don't span multiple lines.

Comment: @user1107685 Does each tag have `id` and `count` in that order, without a space after `count` and only one space between them, using double quotes? *Any* formatting difference in the tag can cause your current regex to break.

Comment: I found the problem - the size of the strings between the tags were too large in some instances and were skipped. I found the limit in PHP. pcre.backtrack_limit is set at 100000 and some strings were larger than this. So I increased this in the .htaccess file using `php_value pcre.backtrack_limit 5000000` and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SimpleXml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) `simplexml_load_file` and then iterate through that object and `explode` it to an array

Comment: Tried this but 'simplexml_load_file' seemed to be very very slow. So went with Palladium's approach.